# Number of tcp connections used by MPI program (MPICH2+nemesis+tcp)

Tags: tcp, parallel-processing, mpi, mpich

How much tcp connections will be used for sending data by MPI program if the MPI used is MPICH2? If you know also about pmi connections, count them separately.

For example, if I have 4 processes and additional 2 Communicators (COMM1 for 1st and 2nd processes and COMM2 for 3rd and 4rd); the data is sent between each possible pair of processes; in every possible communicator.

I use recent MPICH2 + hydra + default pmi. OS is linux, network is switched Ethernet. Every process in on separated PC.

So, here are pathes of data (in pairs of processes):

```
1 <-> 2 (in MPI_COMM_WORLD and COMM1)
1 <-> 3 (only in MPI_COMM_WORLD)
1 <-> 4 (only in MPI_COMM_WORLD)
2 <-> 3 (only in MPI_COMM_WORLD)
2 <-> 4 (only in MPI_COMM_WORLD)
3 <-> 4 (in MPI_COMM_WORLD and COMM2)
```

I think there can be

- Case 1:

Only 6 tcp connections will be used; data sent in COMM1 and MPI_COMM_WORLD will be mixed in the single tcp connection.

- Case 2:

8 tcp connections: 6 in MPI_COMM_WORLD (all-to-all = full mesh) + 1 for `1 <-> 2` in COMM1 + 1 for `3 <-> 4` in COMM2

- other variant that I didn't think about.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Which communicators are being used doesn't affect the number of TCP connections that are established.  For `--with-device=ch3:nemesis:tcp` (the default configuration), you will use one bidirectional TCP connection between each pair of processes that directly communicate via point-to-point MPI routines.  In your example, this means 6 connections.  If you use collectives then under the hood additional connections may be established.  Connections will be established lazily, only as needed, but once established they will stay established until `MPI_Finalize` (and sometimes also `MPI_Comm_disconnect`) is called.

Off the top of my head I don't know how many connections are used by each process for PMI, although I'm fairly sure it should be one per MPI process connecting to the `hydra_pmi_proxy` processes, plus some other number (probably logarithmic) of connections among the `hydra_pmi_proxy` and `mpiexec` processes.

Comment: "If you use collectives then under the hood additional connections may be established." - But if I already have each to each sockets (from point to point), there will be no more connections if I will use collective routines?

Comment: Correct.  Given `p` processes, the greatest possible number of system-wide TCP connections is `p*(p-1)/2`.

Answer (score 0):

I can't answer your question completely, but here's something to consider. In MVAPICH2 for the PMI we developed a tree based connection mechanism. So each node would have log (n) TCP connections at the max. Since opening a socket would subject you to the open file descriptor limit on most OSes, its probable that the MPI library would use a logical topology over the ranks to limit the number of TCP connections.

Comment: I don't understand, if you will have 100 (n=100) processes and there will be each-to-each communication (100*99 one-sided or ~ 100*50 two sided pairs), how they will be done if each of n processes has only log(n) ~< 10 connections?

Comment: Also, at first I want to know not about PMI connections, but about data connections. About your answer - is tree based mechanism for PMI in mpich2 upstream or not?

Comment: I don't know if it is in MPICH2 upstream. It is in MVAPICH2's mpirun_rsh. About the log(n) mechanism, messages are routed via other ranks if there is no direct connection.

Comment: Is this only for PMI or for data too?

Comment: The example I gave was PMI only. I'd imagine libraries need to do something like this (or optimizations such as using shared memory for node-local processes) to reduce the number of open TCP sockets.

Comment: Thanks, I know about shared memory for node-local, and I even want to disable this optimization (send everything via tcp, even if processes are no the same node)

Comment: The easiest way to disable this is to set the environment variable `MPICH_NO_LOCAL=1`.  Or if you are absolutely certain that you don't want to use shared memory then you can configure MPICH2 with `--enable-nemesis-dbg-nolocal`.